# I'm connected via wireless + VPN, internet traffic is still served from my home wireless, correct?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, vpn

I am connected to my work VPN, plus I am connected to my home's local wireless connection.

from what I understand (and it seems to be the case), that internet traffic is served from my home's wireless connection, and any traffic for 185.x.x.x is routed to my works connection via the VPN (that's not the real IP, just saying for example).

Is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

That depends on your VPN and how the routing is configured - there is no single answer that is always correct.

The simplest way to check, other than by asking your work's IT staff who manage the VPN, is to check the default gateway (`netstat -rn` at a command prompt - look for a destination of `default` or `0.0.0.0`).  If the gateway is on your home network then your Internet traffic goes out your home connection.  If the gateway is on the VPN then it goes out your work's connection.

---

Based upon your comment it sounds like your work's VPN is trying to route all traffic across it.  I'm not certain what will happen since with 2 default gateways the `metric` will control which route the traffic takes.  Without further information I would assume that ***all*** traffic is going across your work's link when you're connected to the VPN.

Comment: I have 2 0.0.0.0, the first one's gateway is my local IP, and the 2nd 0.0.0.0 is says 'on-link', and the interface is my works IP 185.x.x.x.